# How to create custom back swipe gesture in UINavigationController on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I found that some of the apps on iOS7 contain a custom back swipe gesture to pop out current view controller from navigation controller. The custom gesture is different from the official one
(interactivePopGestureRecognizer).

The custom gesture can be activated  by swiping from left to right in any position of the screen but not on the edge of the screen only.

eg: Instagram  (Option View swipe back to Profile View)

[image: custom back swipe]

Any ideas on creating this gesture?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword for a simple method is **screenshot**.

When you want to swipe back to **UIViewControllerA** from **UIViewControllerB**, you can take a screenshot(named **UIImageA**) for **UIViewControllerA**. Then you can archived desired effect by the **UIImageA** and the **UIViewControllerB**.

Comment: Yes, check [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/) out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom `UIViewController` transition.

Take a look at these examples for reference:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-transitions/